# I keep feeling my tyre has punctured

Tags: tires, scooter

Often while riding my scooter I get a feel that my rear tyre has gone flat as I experience sudden loss of pick up and can sense the engine is working hard and poor handling(all sort of signs of a flat tyre) but when i stop and have a look it's all ok.
I got a flat tyre recently and had to replace the tube ,I got it inspected by the mechanic he said the wheel and tyre condition is all ok but still I keep feeling the same sometimes.
NOTE: I always maintain the recommended tyre pressure.

Comment: Has the surface you are riding on changed? tarmac to mud?

Comment: @SolarMike i mostly ride it in the city and the roads keep changing from cemented to tar made

Comment: one can imagine issues with wheel bearings or spokes (if spoke wheels) might feel like a flat tire.

Comment: I'm not discarding that there might be something wrong, but in my experience, after a recent flat tire I'd become a little paranoid about my tire. I'd be looking at it once in a while, only to realize it was all alright. It could be the case, but even if it is, I wouldn't turn that into an excuse not to check if everything is in order..

Answer (score 1):

Normally if the engine seems to be working or revving too high without driving the vehicle forward its an indication that there could be an issue with the clutch. If you're not sure this will need to be determined by your mechanic who should be able to inform you far better of the cause of the issue. If the bike has a manual gearbox perhaps something like a clutch cable adjustment is necessary, however if its an automatic different checks will need to be made.

Comment: its not like that my vehicle does not move forward but I experience poor acceleration and that too just for a while

Comment: The bike may well still pull away ok but It still sounds like the clutch is slipping whilst under load, this will result in poor acceleration as the amount of drive available to the rear wheel is reduced due to the slipping clutch.